# When Apache shuts down it leaves many php-cgi processes behind

Tags: apache-http-server, php

If I start Apache and use any of 8 virtual hosts on it for a short while, by going through Wordpress and other CRM's admin UI and blogs/storefronts, then it shuts its `php-cgi` processes down as I bring it down (first, any number of `php-cgi.exe` die, and last the 2x `httpd.exe` die). If instead I let the server run in normal production for a few days, then when I shut it down the 2x `httpd.exe` die but leave a whole bunch of `php-cgi` processes behind. It probably shuts down a tiny handful of all of the `php-cgi` processes that it spawns in the mean time. Tried to wait for a couple of min, but the stale processes still hang on.

These processes are not zombies: they can be killed from task manager of by `taskkill`.

What I checked: that there are no long-running MySQL queries. Databases are quite small, and queries complete within milliseconds, 500 being the absolute worst.

OS: Windows

Apache: 2.4.54

PHP: Both 8.1.6 and 7.4.30

Plenty of available RAM, fast SSD, low CPU load on many available cores.

PHP runs as Fast-CGI.

Comment: What is the parent of these php-cgi processes before and after Apache terminates? Are you using FastCGI?

Comment: `httpd.exe`, before and after.

Comment: I understood from your post that these tasks remain *after* the last httpd.exe has terminated?

Comment: Before and after. Where are we going with this?

Comment: Impossible - a terminated process cannot be parent.

Comment: I can't help it. I am conveying to you the information shown by Sysinternals process explorer. Of course once `httpd.exe` dies all of the `php-cgi.exe` shift to the left as not having a parent. But I gave you exactly that which you had asked for.

Comment: Please post your code responsible for  Connect, Process, Close  - it is likely you are not successful with your CLOSE request, leaving SLEEPing processes.